# Azure AD Device Owners

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, device-management

While working in Azure AD Device Mangement, I come across a cmdlet Add-AzureADDeviceRegisteredOwner which is used to add owners to a device.

I wanted to know what is the purpose of adding multiple owners to a device and how it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

what a device owner could do please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/device-management-azure-portal.

- Having multiple device owner could help the business which have round the clock jobs with different users.
- Having a single owner could limit the device usage and would have an
  increased cost if different devices are allocated to each user.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1102731/index.html